# How to make a infix to postfix function in ARM Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, arm

so I need to create 2 functions, one to convert a given function from infix to postfix in
assembly. The other is to convert a given function from postfix to infix. I created the pseudocode and C code for it, but translating it to ARM is hard. Should I stay with this logic and try to make the ARM assembly based on it, or I should change the way to go for code in assembly 32 bit?? Any help is welcomed

Follows, the pseudocode(algorithm):

1. Scan the infix expression from left to right.
2. If the scanned character is an operand, output it.
3. Else,
   …..3.1 If the precedence of the scanned operator is greater than the precedence of the operator in the 
   stack(or the stack is empty or the stack contains a ‘(‘ ), push it.

   3.2 Else, Pop all the operators from the stack which are greater than or equal to in precedence than that of the scanned operator. After doing that Push the scanned operator to the stack. (If you encounter parenthesis while popping then stop there and push the scanned operator in the stack.)
4. If the scanned character is an ‘(‘, push it to the stack.
5. If the scanned character is an ‘)’, pop the stack and and output it until a ‘(‘ is encountered, and discard both the parenthesis.
6. Repeat steps 2-6 until infix expression is scanned.
7. Print the output
8. Pop and output from the stack until it is not empty.

C code:

```
// C program to convert infix expression to postfix    
//Stack type 

struct Stack 

{ 

    int top; 

    unsigned capacity; 

    int* array; 

}; 


// Stack Operations 

struct Stack* createStack( unsigned capacity ) 

{ 

    struct Stack* stack = (struct Stack*) malloc(sizeof(struct Stack)); 

    if (!stack)  

        return NULL; 

    stack->top = -1; 

    stack->capacity = capacity; 

    stack->array = (int*) malloc(stack->capacity * sizeof(int)); 

    if (!stack->array) 

        return NULL; 

    return stack; 

} 

int isEmpty(struct Stack* stack) 

{ 

    return stack->top == -1 ; 

} 

char peek(struct Stack* stack) 

{ 

    return stack->array[stack->top]; 

} 

char pop(struct Stack* stack) 

{ 

    if (!isEmpty(stack)) 

        return stack->array[stack->top--] ; 

    return '$'; 

} 

void push(struct Stack* stack, char op) 

{ 

    stack->array[++stack->top] = op; 

} 




// A utility function to check if the given character is operand 
int isOperand(char ch) 
{ 
    return (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'); 
} 

// A utility function to return precedence of a given operator 

// Higher returned value means higher precedence 

int Prec(char ch) 

{ 

    switch (ch) 

    { 

    case '+': 

    case '-': 

        return 1; 

    case '*': 

    case '/': 

        return 2; 

    case '^': 

        return 3; 
    } 

    return -1; 
} 


// The main function that converts given infix expression 
// to postfix expression.  


int infixToPostfix(char* exp) 

{ 

    int i, k; 

    // Create a stack of capacity equal to expression size  

    struct Stack* stack = createStack(strlen(exp)); 

    if(!stack) // See if stack was created successfully  
        return -1 ; 

    for (i = 0, k = -1; exp[i]; ++i) 

{ 
        // If the scanned character is an operand, add it to output. 

        if (isOperand(exp[i])) 

            exp[++k] = exp[i]; 

        // If the scanned character is an ‘(‘, push it to the stack. 

        else if (exp[i] == '(') 

            push(stack, exp[i]); 

        // If the scanned character is an ‘)’, pop and output from the stack  
        // until an ‘(‘ is encountered. 

        else if (exp[i] == ')') 

        { 
            while (!isEmpty(stack) && peek(stack) != '(') 

                exp[++k] = pop(stack); 

            if (!isEmpty(stack) && peek(stack) != '(') 

                return -1; // invalid expression   

            else

                pop(stack); 

        } 

        else // an operator is encountered 

        { 

            while (!isEmpty(stack) && Prec(exp[i]) <= Prec(peek(stack))) 

                exp[++k] = pop(stack); 

            push(stack, exp[i]); 

        } 


    } 

    // pop all the operators from the stack 

    while (!isEmpty(stack)) 

        exp[++k] = pop(stack ); 

    exp[++k] = '\0'; 

    printf( "%s", exp ); 
}
```

**And** I also have this pseudocode for arm with the same purpose: (I don't have the C code for this one)

1.While there are input symbol left

2. Read the next symbol from input.
3. If the symbol is an operand Push it onto the stack.
4. Otherwise, the symbol is an operator.
5. If there are fewer than 2 values on the stack Show Error /* input not sufficient values in the expression */
6. Else Pop the top 2 values from the stack. Put the operator, with the values as arguments and form a string.Encapsulate the resulted string with parenthesis.Push the resulted string back to stack.
7. If there is only one value in the stack That value in the stack is the desired infix string.
8. If there are more values in the stack Show Error /* The user input has too many values */

Comment: The double-spacing in your code-block makes it really unpleasant to read, especially given how long it is.

Comment: In assembly, you can use the callstack directly as a stack data structure.  You might want to do that instead of calling `malloc` and managing a struct. Although you could instead reserve space on the stack and manage pointers into it (keep those pointers in registers even across function calls, if you use any function calls instead of just inlining.)

Comment: Do you really need to handle variable-length *strings* as operands?  Or can you treat all input operands as single bytes = 1 character?  That would be one less level of indirection and much easier to manage.